# the member " ..." has no supported translation to SQL error

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

im learning the ropes in LINQ and created a DB and been trying to update a table record but i keep getting the member P.roject1.ChildDBdetails.Id has no supported translation to SQL.
this is the query:

```
public void UpdateChildrecord()
{
    using (ChildDBDataContext ChildDB = new ChildDBDataContext(Con_String))
    {
        IQueryable<ChildDBdetails> query = 
                from c in ChildDB.ChildDBdetails  
                where c.Id == id  
                select c;
        ChildDBdetails updaterecord = query.FirstOrDefault();
        updaterecord.Team = newteam;
        ChildDB.SubmitChanges();            
    }   
}
```

i'm a newbie to linq-to_sql and don't really understand why this is happening.how can i fix the error?
thanks.

TableModel:

```
[Table]
public class ChildDBdetails : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = false, CanBeNull = false)]
    private int id;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanging("Id");
            id = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }

    [Column]
    private string team;

    public string Team
    {
        get { return team; }
        set
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanging("Team");
            team = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Team");
        }
    }

    #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanging

    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanging(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanging != null)
        {
            PropertyChanging(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: `...` is what we looking for. Provide the name. Also, [Column] should be placed on a property, not a private field. Also, what arent you using the DBML designer? It takes care of this.

Comment: @leppie Project1.ChildDBdetails.Id which is a column in the ChildDBdetails table

Comment: @leppie thanks,how do i set it to a property?

Comment: Just use the designer, it will do it properly. Or use the designer on some other DB, so you can inspect the code.

Comment: oh,thanks,it worked,was some problem with how i set the property of the primary key